# StackExchange Metas: use them for technical questions/bug reports or not?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, meta, bug-reports

I just registered at `english` and was going to post a little bug report on `meta.english` concerning the look of the site.

But then, I read the questions already posted there, and there were literally no questions regarding the technical stuff. Instead, they discuss what's appropriate on the site, etc.

So, just wanted to double-check. What's the current policy for posting technical reports? Should they belong to the corresponding `meta`s, or should they be posted here? Given the way the stackexchange site are created, both options make sense to me, so not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's specific to the site itself, it should go on that meta; if it's part of the engine and affects all the SE sites, it should go here. Something about the look of the site probably belongs on the site-specific meta, although I don't think they have much control over that until the site leaves beta

Comment: Ok, done that yesterday. 2 views so far :(